# Оптимизация программы при работе со строками

Tags: java, строки, потоки-данных

Возникла необходимость оптимизировать работу со `String` и `BufferedReader`
Как я понимаю, проблема в большом количестве создаваемых новых экземпляров строки. Очень прошу, при возможности, объяснить, как правильно поступить и почему именно следует писать код.

```
public class ExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private  String extension;
    ExtensionFilter(String extension) {
    this.extension = extension;
    }
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        String f = new File(name).getName();
        return f.indexOf(extension) != -1;
    }
}

public class NonUniqueWords {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
    String dirName = "D://PROJECT";
    String extension = ".java";
    String s;

    FilenameFilter filter = new ExtensionFilter(extension);
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    String[] filenames = dir.list(filter);

    for (String filename : filenames) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://PROJECT//" + filename))) {
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s);
                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    treeSet.add(token);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The amount of non-unique words: " + treeSet.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: А где у вас создается много экземпляров строки?

Comment: А в чем проблема то?

Comment: @pavel163 ,  @rjhdby я подумал что на памяти негативно скажется создание большого количества `String token = tokenizer.nextToken();` тк у меня это порядка 463 элементов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблем со строками здесь не увидел. В качестве оптимизации алгоритма могу предложить вместо `TreeSet` использовать `HashSet`.

`TreeSet` хранит данные в отсортированном виде, но при этом имеет логарифмическую сложность алгоритма добавления элементов. В `HashSet` порядок элементов не определен, а время добавления элементов константное.

Учитывая, что для вашего алгоритма порядок элементов не важен, то эта замена ускорит выполнение кода, но не отразится на результате.